# Recursive program optimization

Tags: algorithm, recursion

How to write a function `countTo(n)` that counts from 1 to n and prints each number without using explicit loops (only recursion)?

The solution must be asymptotically optimal in space and time, *even without tail call optimisation*, given arbitrarily big `n`.

Note: the optimal time complexity is *O*(1) while the optimal space complexity is *O*(log *n*) – even in the iterative case, since the (arbitrarily large) number needs to be printed.

The question comes from [lesswrong.com](http://www.lesswrong.com/lw/2u9/quixey_engineering_screening_questions), and the relevant details are taken from the discussion there (otherwise the question becomes impossible to answer since their original statement makes misleading assumptions).

Comment: can you write a program that "counts from 1 to n"? :)

Comment: I am serious.What do you mean @yi_H?

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call

Comment: @S.Lott As I said in my answer, Python does not perform tail call elimination, so this won't help him. In the context of Python the answer to this question is "No".

Comment: @sepp2k: Python doesn't.  Agreed.  Why ask this in an interview?  Was it to see if the interviewee knew about tail call optimization?  Why ask us?  Was it to find out about tail call optimization?  I don't get the question; it appears to be a failed search for information on tail call optimization.

Comment: The actual question is here: (2nd one) http://lesswrong.com/lw/2u9/quixey_engineering_screening_questions/ So, my question is stated wrong. (I supposed it doesn't matter which language is used). Also, some additional info is provided in the comments, which I interpreted wrong.

Comment: The guys from LessWrong are sometimes … well … difficult. Let me just point to [the comment thread](http://lesswrong.com/lw/2u9/quixey_engineering_screening_questions/#display_t1_2rql) explaining the intricacies of the problem. Simply put, the *original* interview question is stated wrongly. It only admits a solution once the question is stated more carefully.

Comment: I’ve completely restated the question to reflect the originally *intended* question, rather than the one that was actually asked. Unfortunately, this means that all answers are now irrelevant but otherwise the question is trivially answered and rather boring. @genesiss, I hope that’s OK. It wasn’t your fault, by the way, the original formulation on LessWrong was wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the rewritten version to still be recursive, there is no way. Any function call will consume stack space.

There are languages in which calls that are in a tail position will not consume stack space. In such languages you could rewrite your function to be tail-recursive, so it would run in O(1) space. However Python is not one of those languages.

Comment: Why can't you use a CPS-based Python implementation?

Comment: @apc In thoery, you can. But practically, all CPS-based Python implementations are in obscurity. If you want your Python code to be remotely portable, you do not rely on tail recursion optimization.

Comment: @delnan, I could be wrong, but I believe PyPy supports it via RPython. The portability issue seems like a salient point, but what specific portability issues are known to occur?

Comment: "Tail calls are significant because they can be implemented without adding a new stack frame to the call stack" says the wikipedia article.

Comment: @apc Either you express yourself unclearly, or you have some misconceptions about PyPy. The "default" builds of PyPy (both JIT and non-JIT) don't feature anything remotely stackless. There is an optional stackless build, but (1) few people both to install it, (2) an SO question a while ago indicates it doesn't do tail call optimization but only offers some primitives that can be used to that effect, and (3) I remember at least one nasty stackless-exclusive bug. But even if all PyPy binaries has TCO, PyPy isn't terribly widespread either.

Comment: @Joel "There are languages in which calls that are in a tail position will not consume stack space. [...] However Python is not one of those languages." says my post.

Comment: @apc Ignoring whether or not any existing Python implementation eliminates tail calls, Guido van Rossum said that ["the idea that TRE is merely an optimization, which each Python implementation can choose to implement or not, is wrong. Once tail recursion elimination exists, developers will start writing code that depends on it, and their code won't run on implementations that don't provide it"](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html). So any implementation that does eliminate tail call wouldn't be a strict implementation of Python.

Answer (score 1):

Use iteration instead of recursion.

```
def countTo(n):
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        print(n)
```

Comment: Program must stay recursive. I added that to the question.

Answer (score 1):

If python supported tail recursion you could do this:

```
def foo(n):
    print n
    if n > 1:
        foo(n-1)
```

The corresponding c program with any modern gcc version would run in O(1). I'm not aware of any python interpreter that supports tail recursion though - but I don't see any limitations from the language itself that would forbid it.

Comment: That would print the numbers in the wrong order though. To create a tail-recursive version, you'd need two arguments.

Comment: @sepp2k I somehow got the idea that we should count from n to 1.. no idea why. But the other solution should be pretty obvious as well and is left as an exercise to the reader I think ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(n):
    if n > 1:
        foo(n-1)
    print n
```

(Take it as algorithm, not language -specific code.)

The time complexity here will be  O(n*log(n)), if we take that printing of every digit takes the same time.